# Select text in textarea programatically in IE 8

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, textarea, textselection

I have been trying to select text in a textarea programatically based on start and end indexes, but for some reason the selection is offset by a few character locations:

My users make an initial manual selection that I store to a database.
To get the start/end positions of the initial selection I am using the approach outlined here [Caret position in textarea, in characters from the start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-caret-position-in-textarea/3373056#3373056)
(Answered by Tim Down)

I store the selections made by the users, and when they come back to the page I want to default in their previous selections.

My code for making the selection based on the stored positions I extracted using Tim Down's function is the following:

```
  function SelectText(start,end) {
    var textArea = document.getElementById("textArea");

    var inputRange = textArea.createTextRange();
    inputRange.collapse(true);

    inputRange.moveStart("character", start);
    inputRange.moveEnd("character", end - start);

    inputRange.select();
}
```

It seems like the issue is caused by linebreaks/spaces. Does anyone know how to correctly make selections in IE programatically based on start and end?

Comment: Seems like the selection is offset by one character per line break

Comment: IE (and Windows in general) represents line breaks using two characters: `\r\n` (not sure about the order). So you could first replace any sequence of those two characters with a single new line `\n` before creating the range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly if it will help you but you can try to use RangyInputs js library which was developed by Tim Down and available using the following url:  http://code.google.com/p/rangyinputs/

As for me I used Rangy (which is developed by Tim Down too) library for content editable div on one of my projects and it really works well and helped me a lot.

The documentation about supported methods you can find on WiKi page: http://code.google.com/p/rangyinputs/wiki/Documentation

Comment: Thanks. I will do some more testing of this library, but it looks promising